# Shorten the way multiple variables are checked if they are empty

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I'm checking 11 variables if they are empty and based on that adds a value to an array. The variables are not in an array and I'd like to keep them that way if possible.

```
if (!empty($var1)) {
  $Data[] = $var1;
} else {
  $Data[] = ' - ';
}

if (!empty($var2)) {
  $Data[] = $var2;
} else {
  $Data[] = ' - ';
}

if (!empty($var3)) {
  $Data[] = $var3;
} else {
  $Data[] = ' - ';
}
```

Is there a better/shorter way to do the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ternary operators

The best would be to **loop through your variable** if you can do it like so :

**Using ternary operator :**

```
$variables = [ $var1, $var2, $var3 ]
foreach ($variables as $var){
    $Data[] = !empty($var) ? $var: ' - ';
}
```

**Using if/else statement :**

```
$variables = [ $var1, $var2, $var3 ]
foreach ($variables as $var){
    if( !empty($var) ){
        $Data[] = $var;
    }else{
        $Data[] = ' - ';
    }

}
```

But if you cannot and still want to do it individually for each variables :

```
$Data[] = !empty($var1) ? $var1 : ' - ';
$Data[] = !empty($var2) ? $var1 : ' - ';
$Data[] = !empty($var3) ? $var1 : ' - ';
```

Comment: I'd go with the last example, as its the most readable and easily maintained if there are differences in the default values.

Answer (score 2):

If the variables are named in sequence like that you can loop them using variable variables.

```
$i = 1;
while(isset(${"var" . $i})){ 
    if (!empty(${"var" . $i})) 
    {
        $Data[] = ${"var" . $i};
    } else {
        $Data[] = ' - ';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This means you don't need to add them manually to an array as the accepted answer does, and if there some day comes a `$var12` then this code will add that automatically.

See the code in action:
https://3v4l.org/240kA